# Schedule shutdown every day on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: shutdown

I'd like to schedule a shutdown every day at a specific time for my system. I found [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208205/how-to-schedule-shutdown-every-day) that addresses this, but I can't find rc.local
I looked around and it seems like this file doesn't exist on Ubuntu 20.04
I was wondering what the best way to solve this problem is? Should I create this file or is there a file that "substitutes" it?

PS: currently the answers to my question mention `cron`. However, I found the accepted answer to [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120506/how-to-shutdown-linux-at-a-specific-datetime-from-terminal) that recommends not using `cron` for shutdown. I was wondering if someone could elaborate on this option too and why it is not / or is a good option

Comment: Cron? Have a look here: [Nightly server shutdown and auto reboot with cron](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1210222/nightly-server-shutdown-and-auto-reboot-with-cron)

Comment: @Artur Meinild Thanks for the comment. I just added a PS note to my question. Was wondering if you could update your answer accordingly

Comment: I just think cron is easier for this kind of thing. The other method might work as well, but I'm more familiar with cron.

Comment: You should still be able to add the following line in a crontab and get the same effect: `@reboot shutdown -h 22:00 &`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatic shutdown at specified times?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/567955/automatic-shutdown-at-specified-times)

Answer (score 3):

With a quick search, I hopefully found the answer you're looking for

[Automatic shutdown at specified times?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/567955/automatic-shutdown-at-specified-times)

> " Cron will work very well for this.
>
> Add the below line (with tweaks) to the end of /etc/crontab:
>
> 30 23 * * * root shutdown -h now "

From:  [Automatic shutdown at specified times?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/567955/automatic-shutdown-at-specified-times)

Reply if it worked! Good luck!

To run sample.sh twice a day. say 5am and 5pm

0 5,17 * * * shutdown.sh

> where shutdown.sh has the contents
>
> shutdown

- Or, if you want another way:

> ```
> # .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
> # | .------------- hour (0 - 23)
> # | | .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
> # | | | .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
> # | | | | .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
> # | | | | |
> # * * * * * user-name command to be executed
>   0 0 * * 0 root      /sbin/shutdown -h now # power off every sunday at 00:00 am
> ```

Or, alternativly you can use:  `sudo crontab -e` and enter
`0 0 * * 0 root      /sbin/shutdown -r now`

References:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208205/how-to-schedule-shutdown-every-day
- https://www.unix.com/red-hat/173983-cronjob-command-shutdown.html
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/crontab.htm
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto
- https://www.ryadel.com/en/linux-auto-reboot-shutdown-cron-job-crontab-task-scheduler/
- https://linuxize.com/post/cron-jobs-every-5-10-15-minutes/
- [shutdown 5:30pm every day](https://askubuntu.com/questions/538639/shutdown-530pm-every-day?rq=1)
- [recurring scheduled shutdown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243989/recurring-scheduled-shutdown?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: In case it needs step by step explanation:   edit the crontab (nano /etc/crontab) or (gedit /etc/crontab) and type 30 23 * * * root shutdown -h now " to the file's end. for example.

Comment: Here we got 1 more (Ill add this to my answer) (Hopefully helpful for the future)  https://askubuntu.com/questions/538639/shutdown-530pm-every-day?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just added a PS note to my question. Was wondering if you could update your answer accordingly

Comment: I don't have a file called crontab

Answer (score 0):

1. In Ubuntu 20.04 you can execute `crontab -e`, then enter your command at the bottom of the text lines.

   - use `cron` command syntax, it can be viewed at `man cron`.
2. You can use the "Crontab Generator" on this url https://crontab-generator.org/ to calculate your command parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just added a PS note to my question. Was wondering if you could update your answer accordingly

Comment: i just looked up around some forums and i did not find any comments about not using cron, just few more Q&A and recommend to use it.